# Detect Android soft navigation bar height in Ionic 2

Tags: javascript, css, ionic-framework, ionic2

In my Ionic 2 application, I have a grid component with items, that scrolls vertically.

The problem is that in Android devices with soft navigation bar (included in the screen) The scrolling stops before the entire content has revealed (see the bottom of the screen).

Example screenshot of an Android Nexus 5 (**with** soft bottom navigation bar):

[image]

Example screenshot of an iPhone 7 (**without** soft bottom navigation bar):

[image]

**My question is**: How can I detect the soft navigation bar's height (if existent) so that I can add it to the grid's bottom padding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer:**

We can use the global [`screen`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_screen.asp) object, in order to get the dimensions of the entire screen, and the normal `platform.height()` to get the dimensions if the window (without the soft navigation bar's height).

**Sample method:**

```
/**
   * On some Android devices there is a soft navigation bar,
   * which overlaps with the screen.
   * For that reason, we need to compute an extra space for
   * the drawer so that the items in the last
   * row are not shown "behind" the navigation bar
   * @returns {number} the difference in pixels.
   */
  getMarginBottomPropertyForDrawer() {
    const difference = screen.height - this.platform.height();
    return difference;
  }
```

Comment: Where is this.platform defined at? I can't find it referenced anywhere.

Comment: Idt I can edit comments, but just for reference I'm using cordova version 7, and I did some research into platform. It looks like that's an ionic feature and I don't have access to it. Do you know of any workarounds?

Comment: Hi, to have access to this.platform, all you have to do is to inject it in the constructor, like this: constructor(private platform: Platform)

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Paul's answer in case someone else is having this issue:

You can get the height of the soft navigation bar using the original answer, and then inject that as a CSS variable and use it directly in your style:

```
  ngOnInit(){

    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.checkSoftButton();
    });
  }


  private checkSoftButton(){
    const softButton=(screen.height - this.platform.height());
    const body:any=document.querySelectorAll('body');
    body.forEach((e:any)=>{
      e.classList.add('soft-button');
      e.style= '--ion-soft-button:' + softButton + 'px';
    });
  }
```

You can do this once in the first component and then use it in your style like

```
  height:calc(100% - var(--ion-soft-button));
```

or

```
  height:calc(100vh - var(--ion-soft-button));
```

You can even use the soft-button class added to the body in case you need to perform another operation inside your app if there is a soft button.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Cordova Fullscreen Plugin](https://github.com/mesmotronic/cordova-plugin-fullscreen) or add the below settings in your config file,

```
<preference name="Fullscreen" value="true" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Won't this plugin result in both the soft navigation and the status bar to be hidden? I would not want that. I would like just to have a way of measuring the screen height, with the soft navigation bar in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be the following:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', () => {
    var initialHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    window.addEventListener('resize', resizeFunction);
    function resizeFunction() {
        console.log('STATUS BAR HEIGHT', document.documentElement.clientHeight - initialHeight);
        window.removeEventListener('resize', resizeFunction);
    }
    StatusBar.overlaysWebView(true);
});
```

It takes about 150ms from `deviceready`, which you can "hide" by showing the SplashScreen a bit longer :)